# Trouble implementing Destroy in Rails Polymorphic Comments, ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a Rails app that has some Polymorphic relationships, which work, however I'm having trouble implementing the destroy action. The Comment table is the polymorphic table, Subject `has_many :comments` and profile `has_many :comments`. I'm struggling with the ability to Delete comments from the subject show page at the moment(basically a forum). I created an edit_comment_path and can successfully edit and update comments, through the comments controller, however when I try to delete, `@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])` it keeps looking for the Subject.id instead of the Comment.id? The link to delete seems correct so i'm a little puzzled. Please see the code below. Any suggestions or refinements would also be greatly appreciated!

### views/comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<% commentable.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div>
    <hr>
    <% if commentable == @subject %>
      <p><%= comment.body %>  |  Posted by <%= comment.user.email %>, <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) + ' ago' %></p>

      <% if comment.user == current_user %>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_comment_path(comment, subject: 'subject') %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", comment_path, method: :delete %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <p><<%= comment.title %></p>
      <p><%= comment.body %> </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable, notice: "Successfully Posted!"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    if @comment.update(comment_params)
      redirect_to @comment.commentable, notice: "Comment was updated."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

### views/subjects/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @subject.title %></h1>
<p>Created by: <%= @subject.user.email %>, <%= time_ago_in_words(@subject.created_at) + ' ago' %></p>


<%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: {commentable: @subject} %>
<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: {commentable: @subject} %>
```

### config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :locations, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update]
  resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  resources :subjects, only: [:index, :show] do
    resources :comments, module: :subjects
  end
  resources :profiles do
    resources :subjects, module: :profiles
    resources :locations, module: :profiles
    resources :comments, module: :profiles
  end
  resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show]
  root "home#index"

end
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance it looks like

`<%= link_to "Delete", comment_path, method: :delete %>`

should be:

`<%= link_to "Delete", comment_path(comment), method: :delete %>`

I'm assuming that the problem is that the `params[:id]` being passed to your comments#destroy is the Subject's id rather than the Comment's id

Also, your destroy method should look something like:

```
def destroy
    comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    comment.destroy
    redirect_to somewhere
end
```

Comment: Urghh thankyou @sbjluke, that was it. So simple, but I'd been staring at it for too long and couldn't see it. Thanks again